# Asp.net assembly FileNotFoundException after iisreset

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, servicestack

I have a particular web application. Half the time when I run it, I get the following error:

```
    "ErrorCode": "FileNotFoundException",
    "Message": "Could not load file or assembly 'MyNotReallyMissingAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-us, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I have narrowed it down a bit. If I either manually delete the Temporary Asp.Net files that correspond to this site, or changing a dll name and then change it back, or deploying a newly built dlls. Then it will work fine - until I change the web.config or run iisreset. Once that happens, I get nothing but the error mentioned above until a new build is deployed, or I clear out the Temporary Asp.Net files again.

I mention that this is a ServiceStack web service if it helps. I suspect that it doesn't matter though.

I know changing dlls, changing the web.config, recycling the app pool, and probably a few other things cause the web site to recompile, However, what I didn't know is that changing the dlls seems to do something quite different than simply changing the web.config or forcing an app pool recycle.

I looked around for this issue but couldn't find anything except this: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;823196. So I made a new .net 4.0 app pool and changed its identity to NetworkService and made sure the NetworkService user had full access to C:\Windows\Temp. (Note: the server is a Windows 2008 server). The problem still occurs.

Q: What am I doing wrong? What can I do to make sure that my app will continue working through application pool restart/recycle events, and web.config changes?